# "Beauty and the Beast" type short story where the beast wins her by playing cards with the father and cries gems to woo her

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I'm looking for a beauty and the beast type short story where the beast wears a mask and wins the beauty by playing cards with her dad. I remember that the beast cries diamonds or some type of gem and gives them to her to attempt to woo her. At the end the beauty becomes a beast instead of the beast becoming human. I read this in a short story anthology I found in my mum's house so it must be a pre 80s publication.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, and thank you for taking the tour! Please look through our [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) to see if any of the prompts there jog your memory. For example, were there illustrations accompanying the story? Can you remember anything else about other stories in the anthology? Assuming it was in English (and please do clarify if it was not), do you know if it was a translation or not? etc.